# Remove comma and anything after VBA from cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which I use to remove anything after a space.

```
For i = 2 To lastRow33
    If InStr(ws3.Cells(i, 28), " ") > 0 Then
        y = Replace(ws3.Cells(i, 28), " *", "")
        x = Left(y, InStr(y, " ") - 1)
        ws3.Cells(i, 28) = x
    End If
Next I
```

I'm trying to modify it to remove a comma from the end of a string and anything after it. I just keep getting overflow even though I haven't declared any integers only Longs.

```
For i = 2 To lastRow33
    If InStr(ws3.Cells(i, 28), " ") > 0 Then
        y = Replace(ws3.Cells(i, 28), ",*", "")
        x = Left(y, InStr(y, " ") - 1)
        ws3.Cells(i, 28) = x
    End If
Next I
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Declarations Below

```
Dim lastRow33 As Long
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
```

Comment: Can you provide an example to test?

Comment: Please show your declarations as well

Answer (score 3):

You are checking if a space is present in the cell, not for a comma. Changed your code accordingly.

```
For i = 2 To lastRow33
    If InStr(ws3.Cells(i, 28), ",") > 0 Then              `changed space to comma here
        y = Replace(ws3.Cells(i, 28), ",*", "")
        x = Left(y, InStr(y, ",") - 1)                    `changed space to comma here
        ws3.Cells(i, 28) = x
    End If
Next I
```

EDIT:

The overflow error can originate from the InStr function as that will always return an integer. This ofcourse depends on the length of the cell text.

However you are basicly doing the same operation twice. Under Y you replace the comma and everything after that by "".

Then under X you are going to look in the result of Y for comma, which isn't there anymore due to your operation in Y, and take the characters to the left of that. Shorter code to do the same would be:

```
For i = 2 to lastRow33
    If InStr(ws3.Cells(i, 28), ",") > 0 Then
        ws3.Cells(i, 28) = Replace(ws3.Cells(i, 28), ",*", "")
    End if
Next i
```

If this still results in overflow then it is likely caused by the InStr result being to large to be stored in an integer. You can force its value into a long by using the following:

```
For i = 2 to lastRow33
    If CLng(InStr(ws3.Cells(i, 28), ",")) > 0 Then
        ws3.Cells(i, 28) = Replace(ws3.Cells(i, 28), ",*", "")
    End if
Next i
```

Comment: I still get overflow though is that something wrong on my end?

Comment: On what line do you get the error. On the line x= ... ?

Comment: Added Declarations

Comment: The result of InStr is an integer by definition. So perhaps there the overflow error results from. You can try to put CLng() around your InStr() like this: CLng(InStr())

Comment: Still breaks :/ with the code added from above

Comment: expanded my answer

Comment: Where does it break @AngatvirSanghera

Comment: It breaks at cell 270 which contains ######## no matter how large I expand the cell on the replace part

Comment: It contains a formula can I skip over formula's

Comment: You could try Cells().text